# JQM closing multiple select dialog will duplicate browser back button event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, multi-select

Its now 3 days i'm trying to get around this pb, searching around the web and SO.

**Problem:** Go from page 1 to page 2, then to page 3, open in page 3 a multiple select and close it. Then press browser back button goes back to page 2... and to page 1 instantly (as if the back button was pressed twice). The multiple select has to go fullscreen for the pb to occur, this explains why my sample has so many `<option>`.

I isolated the pb in those 3 html files:

**page1.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="content">
            Page 1
            <a data-role="button" href="page2.html">Go to page 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**page2.html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="content">
        Page 2
        <a data-role="button" href="page3.html">Go to page 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**page3.html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
<div data-role="content">
    Page 3
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <select data-native-menu="false" multiple="multiple">
           <option>Open Multi-select</option>
           <option value="0">00</option>
           <option value="1">01</option>
           <option value="2">02</option>
           <option value="3">03</option>
           <option value="4">04</option>
           <option value="5">05</option>
           <option value="6">06</option>
           <option value="7">07</option>
           <option value="8">08</option>
           <option value="9">09</option>
           <option value="10">10</option>
           <option value="11">11</option>
           <option value="12">12</option>
           <option value="13">13</option>
           <option value="14">14</option>
           <option value="15">15</option>
           <option value="16">16</option>
           <option value="17">17</option>
           <option value="18">18</option>
           <option value="19">19</option>
           <option value="20">20</option>
           <option value="21">21</option>
           <option value="22">22</option>
           <option value="23">23</option>
           <option value="24">24</option>
           <option value="25">25</option>
           <option value="26">26</option>
           <option value="27">27</option>
           <option value="28">28</option>
           <option value="29">29</option>
           <option value="30">30</option>
           <option value="31">31</option>
           <option value="32">32</option>
           <option value="33">33</option>
           <option value="34">34</option>
           <option value="35">35</option>
           <option value="36">36</option>
           <option value="37">37</option>
           <option value="38">38</option>
           <option value="39">39</option>
           <option value="40">40</option>
           <option value="41">41</option>
           <option value="42">42</option>
           <option value="43">43</option>
           <option value="44">44</option>
           <option value="45">45</option>
           <option value="46">46</option>
           <option value="47">47</option>
           <option value="48">48</option>
           <option value="49">49</option>
           <option value="50">50</option>
           <option value="51">51</option>
           <option value="52">52</option>
           <option value="53">53</option>
           <option value="54">54</option>
           <option value="55">55</option>
           <option value="56">56</option>
           <option value="57">57</option>
           <option value="58">58</option>
           <option value="59">59</option>
       </select>
   </div>
   Once closed, press browser back button
</div>
```

For some reason, the pb is not reproducible when working on a single page template. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyw27/)

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is no longer reproducible with JQuery Mobile 1.3.0 :

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```